# What is the difference between element class and component element in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I am a beginner in Flutter, I know that an element represents the use of a widget to configure a specific location in the tree, I know that an element is returned by a Widget and I know that the element allows to create the visual graph through an object of rendered, but the `StatelessWidget` and `StatefulWidget` classes return a `StatelessElement` or `StatefulElement` that inherits from `ComponentElement`, which in turn, inherits from `Element`, but what is the difference between `ComponentElement` and `Element`? I know that it is related to the rendering object, but I can't understand it well, I hope you can help me.

Comment: it introduces abstract [build](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ComponentElement/build.html) method that is called in `performRebuild` method, for more check the sources in `widgets/framework.dart`